# Incomplete Microsoft.Graph.User profile data

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

When retrieving data via the Microsoft Graph `User.Read` scope, I am only seeing data for the `businessPhones`, `displayName`, `givenName`, `id`, `jobTitle`, `mail`, `mobilePhone`, `officeLocation`, `preferredLanguage`, `surname` and `userPrincipalName` properties.  I need to be able to expose data for the entire collection of properties, including items such as `companyName`, `state`, `streetAddress`, etc.

I have downloaded two samples from GitHub both of which ran as expected but neither provides the complete set of attributes from the Microsoft.Graph.User object.  I saw the complete set of User properties exposed in an ASP.Net Core demo, so, I know it can be done.  However, I'm not ready for ASP.Net Core just yet.

```
@model Microsoft.Graph.User
@{
    ViewBag.Current = "Profile";
}
<h1>Profile</h1>
<table class="table">
    @{
        var properties = Model.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var child in properties)
        {
            object value = child.GetValue(Model);
            string stringRepresentation;
            if (!(value is string) && value is IEnumerable<string>)
            {
                stringRepresentation = 
                    "[" 
                    + string.Join(", ", (value as IEnumerable<string>).OfType<object>().Select(c => c.ToString()))
                    + "]";
            }
            else
            {
                stringRepresentation = value?.ToString();
            }

            <tr>
                <td> @child.Name </td>
                <td> @stringRepresentation </td>
            </tr>
            }
    }
</table>
```

As noted, the code iterates the User object properties as expected but only provides a subset of available results.  I was able to validate my suspicions by retrieving my user profile data from the Microsoft Graph Explorer site and comparing it with the results from my app.  The Graph Explorer provided data not available through my app.

What am I missing?  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I am now able to extract the attributes needed using $Select.

Answer (score 0):

When requesting a `User` resource without a [`$select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#select-parameter) query parameter, Graph will insert a [default `$select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) automatically:

```
$select=businessPhones,displayName,givenName,jobTitle,mail,mobilePhone,officeLocation,preferredLanguage,surname,userPrincipalName,id"
```

If you don't want the default set of properties, you need to construct your own [`$select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#select-parameter) parameter:

```
$select=id,displayName,companyName
```

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

> Note: Getting a user returns a default set of properties only (*businessPhones, displayName, givenName, id, jobTitle, mail, mobilePhone, officeLocation, preferredLanguage, surname, userPrincipalName*). Use `$select` to get the other properties and relationships for the [user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0) object.